# Codeigniter 4 autoroute modules

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm creating an application under CI4.

folder structure:

[image]

Class:

```
namespace App\Modules\Dashboard\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\AppBaseController;

class Dashboard extends AppBaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view( THEME.'/modules/dashboard/dashboard' );
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Routes code:

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Modules');
```

Under the url `/dashboard` I receive a 404 response:
[image]

How could I create a correct routing automatically?

PD: If I create a Route for `/dashboard`, it works fine

Comment: Automatic routing is a bad idea. Defining routes both documents your code and makes sure you are using what you are expecting to use.

Comment: Remove `$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Modules');` In this case it is expecting Dashboard class inside `App\Modules`

Comment: @quasi did you get a solution to this ?